# How to make a div disappear on click and reappear in another parent with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am working on a code that is a rendition of this code here `/oceatoon/pen/CGfrj`. I am trying to make it a bit more complex, so that when a user clicks on his choice, the choosed icon will disappear from the menu and will appear on the top-left container and simultaniously the CU´s choice will appear on the top-right container.

I tried a more simplistic way, just to make the divs float up. But now I do not know how to make the CPU´s choice float up-right and how to reset the game. how do I tell my code which one is the CPU´s choice? I tried to create a variable

```
var = cpuChoice 
CpuChoice = gameArea[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameArea.length)];
```

and then I tried to make it float right by doing this:

```
 cpuChoice.animate({ top:"5px", left:"70px" }, 1500 );
```

I receive an error that cpuChoice.animate is not a function, but it is inside the

```
 $('#rock.choice').click(function() {
```

I then tried adding a reset button and created an .onclick function, but it did not do anything. As you will see, when you click on paper, the other options will disappear, because I tought I will andd the reset button and show all the options in order on click. But the button did not work.
Anyone has any suggestions?

Here is the fiddle **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Daria90/rdLyb79p/31/)**

Comment: /oceatoon/pen/CGfrj should that be a path? Because it isn't. 'var = cpuChoice' is not valid JS code. In the next line you write 'CpuChoice' (capitalized), this is not correct either because such languages are case-sensitive. Please resolve these issues and update your question accordingly!

Comment: @Verena Haunschmid you are right, I am sorry i posted it wrong.  I meant to write var cpuChoice= '' ; 
cpuChoice = gameArea[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameArea.length)]; This is what I tried and did not work.

Comment: Can you correct it and tell us if you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the here https://jsfiddle.net/rdLyb79p/33/

Below is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.choice').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock'];
        var userChoice = $(this).data("index");
        var cpuChoice = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) % 5; 

        var matchResult = match(choices[userChoice], choices[cpuChoice]);

        $("#blowupUser").html(
            '<div class="choice">\
                <i class="fa fa-hand-rock-o" style="font-size:50px;color:#000;"></i>\
                <span class="color"></span>\
                <span class="name">'+choices[userChoice]+'</span>\
            </div>'
        );

        $("#blowupCPU").html(
            '<div class="choice">\
                <i class="fa fa-hand-rock-o" style="font-size:50px;color:#000;"></i>\
                <span class="color"></span>\
                <span class="name">'+choices[cpuChoice]+'</span>\
            </div>'
        );

        $('#info').html('<h3>You <span class="' + matchResult.toLowerCase() + 's">' + matchResult + '</span></h3>');
    });


    function match(userChoice, cpuChoice) {
        var matchResult = ['lost', 'win', 'tied'];
        var result;

        if(userChoice == 'rock') {
            if (cpuChoice == 'rock') {
                result = 2;
            } else if (cpuChoice == 'spock' || cpuChoice == 'paper') {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else if(userChoice == 'paper') {
            if (cpuChoice == 'paper') {
                result = 2;
            } else if (cpuChoice == 'scissors' || cpuChoice == 'lizard') {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else if(userChoice == 'scissors') {
            if (cpuChoice == 'scissors') {
                result = 2;
            } else if (cpuChoice == 'rock' || cpuChoice == 'spock') {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else if(userChoice == 'lizard') {
            if (cpuChoice == 'lizard') {
                result = 2;
            } else if (cpuChoice == 'rock' || cpuChoice == 'scissors') {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else if(userChoice == 'spock') {
            if (cpuChoice == 'spock') {
                result = 2;
            } else if (cpuChoice == 'paper' || cpuChoice == 'lizard') {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }

        return matchResult[result];
    }

}); // End $(document).ready
```

Note: I removed some of the designs and the scoring.

Comment: Neil, thanks a lot. That gives me something to start with. I  just want to ask you: how dod you post the fiddle link withouth copying the whole code?